# Shared folders VMware Workstation Ubuntu Host & Guest

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, vmware, shared-folders

I am trying to setup shared folders in my Lubuntu 16.04 guest running on an Ubuntu 14.04 host in VMware Workstation 12 Pro.
I have tried installing VMware tools and also open-vm-tools with no luck. When i look under the /mnt directory there is a file called: hgfs but it says the file type is "inode/x-corrupted type" and i cannot open it. I also dont see a place to choose what shared folders i want shared from my Ubuntu host (like the windows version has).

Thanks
Luke

Comment: i have the same problem did you fixed that ?